# How to implement update_or_create inside create method of ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

The code:

```
class OTP(AppModel):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[6789]\d{9}$', message="phone no. is invalid.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=10, unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.phone_number) + ": "+str(self.code)

class OTPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    code = serializers.CharField(max_length=None, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = OTP
        fields = ('id', 'code', 'phone_number')
        read_only_fields=('id', 'code')

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        phone_number = validated_data.pop("phone_number")
        otp, created = OTP.objects.update_or_create(
            phone_number=phone_number, defaults={"code": generate_otp()})
        return otp
```

I am trying to do `update_or_create` inside the `create` method of the `django-rest-framework`'s `ModelSerializer`.

But, the field `phone_number` inside the model `OTP` must be `unique`. Hence the `unique=True`.

I was able to post a `phone_number` and create the object. But, posting the same `phone_number` again throws error `otp with this phone number already exists`, instead of updating it if it already exists as I have overridden the `create` method. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could make `phone_number` NOT required and then manually do the check. You get the error, because DRF validated `phone_number` before you do. So, basically, the solution could be the following (serialiser code only):

```
class OTPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    code = serializers.CharField(max_length=None, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = OTP
        fields = ('id', 'code', 'phone_number')
        read_only_fields=('id', 'code')
        extra_kwargs = {'phone_number': {'required': False}}

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        phone_number = validated_data.pop("phone_number")
        otp, created = OTP.objects.update_or_create(
        phone_number=phone_number, defaults={"code": generate_otp()})
        return otp
```

Comment: No. the `phone_number` is required. And the problem is: `UniqueValidator` validates before reaching `create` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the validator inside your serializer class instead of inside the model class. So have your serializer class look something like this:

```
class OTPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    code = serializers.CharField(max_length=None, required=False)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[6789]\d{9}$', message="phone no. is invalid.")  # add this line
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(validators=[phone_regex])  # and this line
    
    class Meta:
        model = OTP
        fields = ('id', 'code', 'phone_number')
        read_only_fields=('id', 'code')

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        phone_number = validated_data.pop("phone_number")
        otp, created = OTP.objects.update_or_create(
            phone_number=phone_number, defaults={"code": generate_otp()})
        return otp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/) to do this in a clean way. Simply, you can send a `created` variable to a `receiver` which you define, and deal with it based on either your object was created or not. in the case of the REST response, just override the `create` method in the Serializer to return data based on the state you're in, or the `get/post/patch` method you're using in the APIView to not return `serializer.data`, and instead return whatever you want it to.
Here is an example for a signal receiver:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.OTP_MODEL)
def update(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # Do Something
    else:
        # Do Some Other thing
```

Comment: Just be careful with Signals as they aren't atomic. Your serializer can commit data and anything the signal does to the database is in its own transaction. UNLESS you decorate the view with @atomic from django.db.transaction